# Unable to grasp how assigning True to variable work in this piece of code

Tags: python

```
myList = []
swapped = True
num = int(input("How many elements do you want to sort: "))

for i in range(num):
    val = float(input("Enter a list element: "))
    myList.append(val)
while swapped:
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(myList) - 1):
        if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:
            swapped = True
            myList[i], myList[i + 1] = myList[i + 1], myList[i]
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever two elements in the array will get swap this executes:

```
if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]: # this checks if the elements are out of order
     swapped = True
```

if on any given iteration there are no swaps, the flag swapped will remain its default value, false, which would mean that the array is in order, or sorter.

Comment: why we have to write swapped= True above.. if the if statement doesnt hold condition the swap code will not execute and iterate over for next turn

Comment: @tHuNdErAtEr because there will be situations in which you will have to do multiple iterations through the data in order to sort it. Unless you set swapped=True when you swap, the while loop will terminate after the very first iteration. It will be very rare that you are able to sort an array of data with a single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The `True` value of `swapped` variable in this code is to make the while loop to make the next iteration.
So in case the `if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:` is `True` then the `swapped` will be `True` and male the while loop to keep on itarating.

Comment: what if the    if  myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:     is false

Comment: The while loop will not make another iteration and exit the loop since the `swapped` will be False because at the beginning of the while loop there is `swapped = False`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Bubble Sort algorithm

- https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/3531-sorting-algorithms-as-dances.html

The loop condition is `while swapped:`. Thus you need to set `swapped = True` beforehand so it executes the first loop.

The loop starts off by setting `swapped = False`, then for loops over `myList` to check if any of the items needs to be swapped. It then sets `swapped = False` to let the while loop know it needs at least one more pass over the data.

The algorithm will continue to loop over the data until it has managed to do one complete loop over `myList` without encountering any two elements in need of swapping. This implies the data has been successfully sorted.

As a side note, Barack Obama would advise against using Bubble Sort as the most efficient way to sort a million 32-bit integers.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8

Comment: but to enter loop we can write while True: also

Comment: In this case `while swapped` is correct, as we have to conduct a search inside the loop. To use `while True` would require adding  `if not swapped: break` as the last line in the while loop, which is essentially turning it into a `do while` loop.